# Open Colorbox on page load

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have been trying to make the colorbox work on page load, but I can see only the loading with a plain background. I used this code

`$.fn.colorbox({id:'', title:'',open:true});`

You can find the demo here

http://www.bloggermint.com/demos/popupsub/colorbox/example5/index.html

Comment: If kei's answer is acceptable, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 42):

EDITED:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $.colorbox({width:"30%", inline:true, href:"#subscribe"});
        }); 
</script>
```